# Jar file won't run with SWT Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swt

I executed into a jar file on MacOS. When running through terminal I get the following:

```
Joshs-MacBook-Pro:Desktop josh$ java -jar Untitled.jar
***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions. Use vmarg -XstartOnFirstThread
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4711)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4626)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4597)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:837)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1446)
    at Login.open(Login.java:39)
    at Login.main(Login.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the warning message said you must specify the `-XstartOnFirstThread` flag on the `java` command when running SWT on macOS.

```
java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar Untitled.jar
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed most of the problem!

Comment: Is there anyway I can somehow add this to the build file so a user doesn't have to execute that way. It opens the first 2 SWT windows just fine, but not the JFrame window. Crashes when the JFrame window is opened

Comment: JFrame is Swing not SWT. Mixing Swing with SWT is always problematic, if at all possible stick to SWT or Swing not both. For just a jar I don't think there is any way to avoid the command line argument. An Eclipse RCP can be built as a proper macOS app and hide that stuff, but that is quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: I appreciate it. This is all for a semester long project. It's one thing to easily run it through Eclipse without issue, another to export it to share.

Answer (score 0):

What is the question here?

- Is this a bug? > Probably not
- Do you have to create a SWT display in the main thread? > Probably yes
- Do we need some code to see what you
  are doing? > Definitly yes